# timing and delays on javascript

Tags: javascript

Im changing the page background of a from white to black following a sequence of 1 and 0. At the moment I manage to make it work were the black and white background changes with the same delay:

```
var syncinterval = setInterval(function(){
    bytes = "10101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101";

    bit = bytes[i];
    output_bit(bit);

    i += 1;
    if (i > bytes.length) {
        clearInterval(syncinterval);

        i = 0;
        for (i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
            tbits = input[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(2);
            while (tbits.length < 8) tbits = '0' + tbits;
            bytes += tbits;
        }
        console.log(bytes);
    }
}, sync_speed);
```

Complete working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kn48Z/

How can I modify the function to make the white background last for sync_speed seconds and the black background for other any value?

Comment: Thanks for the demo, I just had a seizure.

Comment: That demo is dangerous for epileptic people, just FYI. Seriously.

Comment: Use a recursive funtion instead, and set the timeout based on the color

Comment: actually no @Sergio, epileptic attacks are triggered by 100hz frequencies. Im way below that value

Comment: @DomingoSL: use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` and call it every time with different value. Istead of using `clearInterval` - just don't call `setTimeout` anymore

Comment: @DomingoSL what about now? Still below 100hz http://jsfiddle.net/kn48Z/3/

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do, try placing your code into a separate function and use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp). This will give you more control over what you're trying to accomplish.

I modified your code a bit. I check to see if bit is 1 (which I'm assuming is white), if it is, it will run backgroundOrSomething within sync_speed seconds. If it's not, it will run backgroundOrSomething within otherTime. I set otherTime to 1 second, just for giggles.

```
    function backgroundOrSomething (){
    bytes = "10101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101";

    bit = bytes[i];
    output_bit(bit);

    i += 1;
    if(i > bytes.length) {
        i = 0;
        for (i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
            tbits = input[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(2);
            while (tbits.length < 8) tbits = '0' + tbits;
            bytes += tbits;
        }
        console.log(bytes);
    }

    otherTime = 1000;

    if (bit == 1)
        setTimeout(backgroundOrSomething, sync_speed);
    else
        setTimeout(backgroundOrSomething, otherTime);
}

setTimeout(backgroundOrSomething, sync_speed);
```

The last setTimeout at the bottom of the code will be the first to execute backgroundOrSomething.

Answer (score 0):

As above you'll need to use a set interval as follows:

```
var bit = 0;
var syncInterval = setInterval(function() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = bit == 0 ? 'black' : 'white';
    bit = 1;
}, 3000);

var stopInterval = setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(syncInterval);
}, 50000);
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/kn48Z/4/. Note slowed down background switch so it should give a fit.